# Python requests How to get a page without downloading all images?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I need to parse a webpage and it has a lot of images, each request takes a lot of time because of it.

Can I use requests.get to get only html content without waiting for images?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you GET a page, you only download the page itself anyway.

```
import requests

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394209/python-requests-how-to-get-a-page-without-downloading-all-images'

# This will yield only the HTML code
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

The page HTML contains references to images, but the GET request does not follow them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stupid, sometimes ask really stupid questions. It was just javascript and map loading. I will accept your answer. No wonder there were no google results for this question.

Comment: Just so you know, you're not the only one who thought the images were downloaded too, haha